# Why I cannot save file with Chinese characters when using Python 2.7.11 IDLE?

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, python-idle

I just downloaded the latest Python 2.7.11 64bit from its official website and installed it to my Windows 10. And I found that if the new IDLE file contains Chinese character, like 你好, then I cannot save the file. If I tried to save it for several times, then the new file crashed and disappeared.

I also installed the latest python-3.5.1-amd64.exe, and it does not have this issue.

How to solve it?

***More：***
A example code from wiki page, https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%B8%AD%E5%AD%90%E7%B1%BB%E5%9E%8B

***If I past the code here, StackOverflow alays warn me: Body cannot contain "I just dow". Why?***

Thanks!

[image]

**More:**
I find this config option, but it does not help at all.
IDLE -> Options -> Configure IDLE -> General -> Default Source Encoding: UTF-8

***More:***
By adding `u` before the Chinese code, everything will be right, it is great way. Like below:
[image]

Without `u` there, sometimes it will go with corrupted code. Like below:
[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimal working sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 2.x uses ASCII as default encoding, while Python 3.x uses UTF-8. Just use:
 `my_string.encode("utf-8")`
to convert ascii to utf-8 (or change it to any other encoding you need)

You can also try to put this line on the first line of your code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: That doesn't help; the issue is IDLE can't even save a python file with any of those chars in it

Answer (score 2):

Python 2 uses ASCII as its default encoding for its strings which cannot store Chinese characters. On the other hand, Python 3 uses Unicode encoding for its strings by default which can store Chinese characters.

But that doesn't mean Python 2 cannot use Unicode strings. You just have to encode your strings into Unicode. Here's an example of converting your strings to Unicode strings.

```
>>> plain_text = "Plain text"
>>> plain_text
'Plain text'
>>> utf8_text = unicode(plain_text, "utf-8")
>>> utf8_txt
u'Plain_text'
```

The prefix `u` in the string, `utf8_txt`, says that it is a Unicode string.

You could also do this.

```
>>> print u"你好"
>>> 你好
```

You just have to prepend your string with `u` to signify that it is a Unicode string.

Comment: Adding `u` is great!

Answer (score 0):

When using Python 2 on Windows:

1. For file with Unicode characters to be saved in IDLE, a line

   ```
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
   ```

   has to be added in its beginning.
2. And for Unicode characters to show correctly in console output in Windows, if running **a script, saved in a file**, in IDLE console or in Windows shell, strings have to be prepended with `u`:

   ```
   print u"你好"
   print u"Привет"
   ```

   But in interactive mode, I discovered no need for this with cyrillic.

Answer (score 0):

even in python 3.7 I still experience the same issue, UTF-8 still does the trick